# Is it possible to install python3-pyqt5 > 5.15 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, pyqt5

I am trying to use a piece of software that requires PyQt5 but I am having a bug that I think might be related to the version of the package that is installed.

The version I have is 5.14.1, and as seen on Launchpad, it's the latest version available for Ubuntu 20.04.

I'd like to try to update it to a version newer than 5.15, but these only seen to be available for other versions of Ubuntu (either the non LTS or the not yet released new LTS).

Is it possible to somehow install this version on my version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Etrinitronx/+archive/ubuntu/focal-backport-buildeps) to get *5.15.2+dfsg-1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1* on 20.04 LTS as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:trinitronx/focal-backport-buildeps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

And if you find it bad, you can revert to previous version by running below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:trinitronx/focal-backport-buildeps
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! For future reference, how do I find a third-party PPA when I need it?

Comment: I found PPAs using https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas or by locally installed cool python script from https://github.com/anenasa/pyppasearch . Official packages are always searchable on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ .